# Created image from text cannot be displayed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have converted text to Image(.png) using ASP.NET C# in Visual Studio 2010. But the image created cannot be displayed in the browser after submitting and it shows an message

> The image "http://localhost:49670/WebSite1/Default.aspx" cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.

During debugging there is no error or warning or anything like that. How can I resolve this?

Comment: please show the code that generates the image and sends it to the browser.

Comment: if you could put some code example of how you output the image , also what is the error text?

Comment: doesn't appear to be a .png from the path....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Url there is a chance that you are rendering image intermixed with HTML content... 
Using ASHX is better option to render images - check out http://aspalliance.com/1322_Displaying_Images_in_ASPNET_Using_HttpHandlers.all

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(string sImageText)
        {
            Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);

            int intWidth = 0;
           int intHeight = 0;

            // Create the Font object for the image text drawing.
            Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 20, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

           // Create a graphics object to measure the text's width and height.
           Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

           // This is where the bitmap size is determined.
           intWidth = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, objFont).Width;
           intHeight = (int)objGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, objFont).Height;

           // Create the bmpImage again with the correct size for the text and font.
           objBmpImage = new Bitmap(objBmpImage, new Size(intWidth, intHeight));

           // Add the colors to the new bitmap.
           objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

           // Set Background color
           objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
           objGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
           objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
           objGraphics.DrawString(sImageText, objFont, new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(102, 102, 102)), 0, 0);
           objGraphics.Flush();

           return (objBmpImage);
       }
```